# How to take part in excel files

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet

Hello sorry for my english.
I have to select a row of a excel file, put any new data and save them.
In the end I see that the excel file is always larger than before although the data are not increased but it looks to be created of the blank columns to the right.
I think this because when I execute the following statement

```
var wb = openWorkBook(filename);
var ws = wb.Worksheet("CNF");
IXLRow row = ws.Row(device.Ordinal - 1 + FirstRow);
for (int j = 0; j < MAXCOLS; ++j)
{
IXLCell cell = row.Cell(j + FirstCol);
...}
```

as range goes from A1 to XFD1048576.
Although after I take the line of my interest and cycle of 100 columns when I go

```
wb.Save();
```

the file increases.
So I ask you if you have a method to take only a part of a file then for example take already suffered from a limited number of columns, starting from education `var ws = wb.Worksheet("CNF");`.

Thank you

Comment: what kind of Excell library are u using for c#? maybe instead of `MAXCOLS` request the amount of columns for that row/worksheet to make sure you do not iterate over to many columns?

Comment: I use ClosedXML.dll. I'm sorry but your second question I did not understand.

Comment: you are using a variable called `MAXCOLS` maybe this way you iterate over to many cells, generating the extra size in the worsheet?

Comment: Does de file size also increase again when you open the excell file again and save it again or does it only happen the first time?

Comment: MAXCOLS is 100 the problem seems to be on the line "var ws = wb.Worksheet (" CNF ");"
that as the range is A1 to XFD1048576 I would like to know if there is a way to restrict, from there the number of columns.
It not with a constant trend, but always increases.